# Attach foldername to first column of file

Tags: unix, awk, batch-processing

I have a list of files that do have the identical filename but are in different subfolders. The values in the files are seperated with a tab.

I would like to attach to all of the files "test.txt" an additional first column with the foldername and if merge to one file in the end (they all have the same header for the columns).
The most important command though would be the merging.
I have tried to many commands now that did not work so I guess I am missing an essential step with awk...

Current structure is:

```
mainfolder

    |_>Folder1
       |_>test.txt
    |->Folder2
       |_>test.txt
    .
    .
    .
```

This is where I would like to get to per file before merging all of the,

```
#Name   Count   FragCount   Type    Left    LeftB   Right   RightB  Support FRPM    LeftBD  LeftBE  RightBD RightBE annots
RFP1A   13  10  REF RFP1A_ins   chr3:3124352:+  RFP1A_ins chr3:5234143:+ confirmed  0.86    TA 1.454    AC 1.564 ["INTRACHROM."]

#Samplename #Name   Count   FragCount   Type    Left    LeftB   Right   RightB  Support FRPM    LeftBD  LeftBE  RightBD RightBE annots
Sample1 RFP1A   13  10  REF RFP1A_ins   chr3:3124352:+  RFP1A_ins chr3:5234143:+ confirmed  0.86    TA 1.454    AC 1.564 ["INTRACHROM."]
```

Thanks so much!!

D

Comment: it would be better if you posted some 2 input fragments from 2 input `_test.txt` files and the final expected result

Comment: just added this information. thanks roman!

Comment: FYI "folder" is a Windows term, in UNIX the equivalent are "directories". Please update your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now you have a directory structure but no input files and an output file that doesn't contain the directory names so it's not as useful as it could/should be.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Oops, you forgot to include your code. Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see awk in your question. Please add your attempt so far. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that folks answering can be confident they're on the same track as you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might do the trick:

```
$ cd mainfolder
$ awk '(NR==1){sub("#","#Samplename\t"); print}                # print header
       (FNR==1){next}                                          # skip header
       {print substr(FILENAME,1,match(FILENAME,"/")-1)"\t"$0 } # add directory
      ' */test.txt > /path/to/newfile.txt
```

Comment: This is amazing. it did the trick all at once! Thanks so much!